# Connect HTTP thread handlers to SessionPools.

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, c++11, poco-libraries

We are using the model set up in the PoCo-project library documentation. A thread/Handler is spawned for every connection to the http server. We want to connect each thread to a shared SessionPoolContainer(SPC). We are working on the assumption that we should instantiate the SPC in the HandlerFactory and give the handler a reference to the SPC.

```
    class Handler: public Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandler{
    public:
      Handler(SessionPoolContainer &spc){
        //Here is where it goes wrong. "spc is private."
        SessionPool sp = spc.getPool("p1");
        //Todo fetch a session once we have the sessionpool reference.  
      }

      void handleRequest(Poco::Net::HTTPServerRequest& request, Poco::Net::HTTPServerResponse& response){
        //Do stuff.  
      }
     };

    class HandlerFactory : public Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandlerFactory{
    public:
      SessionPoolContainer spc;

      Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandler* createRequestHandler(const Poco::Net::HTTPServerRequest &request){
        Poco::Data::MySQL::Connector::registerConnector();
        AutoPtr<SessionPool> p1 = new SessionPool("MySQL", "host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;db=testdb2;user=bachelor;password=bachelor;compress=true;auto-reconnect=true");
    spc.add(p1);

        if (request.getContentType().compare("Application/JSON")) {
          return new Handler(spc);
          }
        }
      };

    class MyWebHTTPServerApplication : public Poco::Util::ServerApplication{
    protected:

      int main(const std::vector<std::string> &args){
        // Instanciate HandlerFactory
        Poco::Net::HTTPServer server(new HandlerFactory(), socket, pParams);
        server.start();
        //SIC
      }
    };
```

The error we get from this is (from the 3rd line):
        /home/notandi/git/poco-1.7.2-all/cmake_install/debug/include/Poco/Data/SessionPool.h:187:9: error: 'Poco::Data::SessionPool::SessionPool(const Poco::Data::SessionPool&)' is private
         SessionPool(const SessionPool&);
         ^ /home/notandi/QT/MySQLWithPool/main.cpp:68:41: error: within this context 
SessionPool sp = spc.getPool("p");

From where I'm sitting this just needs to work and have the reference passed around.

I have tried to "friend class Handler;" in Handler with no change in status. 
The relevant part of SessionPoolContainer looks like:

```
    private:
      typedef std::map<std::string, AutoPtr<SessionPool>, Poco::CILess> SessionPoolMap;
      SessionPoolContainer(const SessionPoolContainer&);
      SessionPoolContainer& operator = (const SessionPoolContainer&);
      SessionPoolMap  _sessionPools;
      Poco::FastMutex _mutex;
```

Do I edit and recompile PoCo with SessionPoolContainer with "friend class Handler;"? How do I get around this or am I just thinking this all wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the posted code, it looks like the pool container is not needed at all because `p1` pool is never added to the pool container; so, even if you could compile, `spc` would contain no session pools; using SessionPoolContainer makes sense only if you are connecting to multiple databases, in which case you have to add session pool to the pool container:

spc.add(p1);

However, if there is no need for SessionPoolContainer, then just pass the reference to SessionPool to the handler and get a session from it:

```
class Handler: public Poco::Net::HTTPRequestHandler{
  public:
    Handler(SessionPool &sp){
      Session s = sp.get(); 
    }
    //...
};
```

Look at [this code](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/poco-1.7.3/Data/testsuite/src/SessionPoolTest.cpp#L49) to get a better understanding how to use session pools and containers thereof.

Comment: We are using multiple databases.

Comment: spc.add(p1); > is run in the HandlerFactory. We are using multiple databases. Thx for the example. I'm not good at reading C++ code but your code looks like it runs everything in one class, perhaps not so relevant for my problem?

Comment: It is relevant, if you have multiple databases, add each pool to the `SessionPoolContainer`, pass a `SessionPoolContainer&` to the handler and get session you want from it: `Session s(spc.get("MySQL:///host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;db=testdb2;user=bachelor;password=bachelor;compress=true;auto-reconnect=true""))`. Or, get the pool: `SessionPool sp(spc.get("p1")` and then session: `Session s(sp.get())`.
But, if you are not good at reading C++, success at writing it is not likely, either.

Comment: It complains about the value being private like before. I can pass the "SessionPoolContainer&" to the handler but I can't use value, because it is private.

Comment: It is because you are trying to make a copy. Get a reference to the session pool: `SessionPool& sp = spc.getPool("p1");`

Comment: Thanks. Don't know how I got this wrong. Probably put the & in the wrong place.